# Add To Scene OpenGL

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl

I am trying to create a simple function that adds openGL code into my MainLoop.

For example, using `win->AddToScene("glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES); glVertex3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f); glEnd(); ");`

I am trying to do this using Arrays, but it isn't working as far what I have.

Code:

```
std::vector< int > arr;

void Window::MainLoop()
{

    do
    {
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

        glFlush();
        glfwPollEvents();

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++)
        {
            arr[i];
        }


        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

    }


    while(running && !glfwWindowShouldClose(window));
}

void Window::AddToScene(char child[100]){
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i++){
        arr.push_back(*child);
    }
}
```

Are the arrays a way to do it, or do I have to do something completely else?

Thanks

Comment: C is not an interpreted language, you can't execute strings that contain C code at runtime (at least, not easily).

Comment: Ah, that explains why. Well, is there even a way to execute a void in a main loop using arrays?

Comment: have a look at std::function and lambdas

Comment: As others said, you should look into `std::function` and lambdas. But also think right away how you're going to remove the objects from the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Props for creativity. Just FYI what you want to do wouldn't work **that** way in interpreted languages either. In those you'd have to use some `eval` statement.

It should be noted that it's perfectly possible to implement an *interpreter* for a small custom toy language (or rather command execution list) in C that does exactly as you envision.

However as far as adding geometry to your scene goes: *You're barking up the completely wrong tree!* A scene solely consists of **what** is drawn not **how** it is drawn. Your mistake in thinking is, that you mistook the `glVertex` calls as what is important. What's actually important are the numbers that go *into* it.

Think about something like this:

```
glBegin(…);
for(size_t i = 0; i < vertices.length(); ++i){
    glVertex3f(vertices[i].x, vertices[i].y, vertices[i].z);
}
glEnd();
```

However all these function calls are super inefficient. What you actually want to do is rather this, i.e. using *Vertex Arrays*:

```
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, &vertices[0]);
glDrawArrays(…, 0, vertices.length());
```

Last step would be dropping the old style OpenGL functions and transition to generic vertex attributes and vertex buffer object; but that is easy enough once you master old style vertex arrays.